# Selecting Elements By Id in Purescript

Tags: purescript, halogen

Is there a function in `purescript-halogen` to select an element by it's `id`, or do I need to custom role it (which would seem very strange to me).

I'm reading through the documentation on Pursuit, and I see a `selectElement` function in `Util`, but nowhere do I see something that lets me select by `id`.

I can use `getElementById :: ElementId -> NonElementParentNode -> Eff () (Nullable Element)` to get an `Element`, but I do not know how to turn this `Element` into an `HTMLElement`.

The type search feature in Pursuit is also lacking, so I apologize for this naive question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't something you should generally do when working with libraries that use a virtual DOM, since if you save a reference to an element by id it can end up stale and referring to a totally different element, or an element that is no longer attached to the DOM.

The way to get hold of an element is to use `ref`, there is an example of using it [in this section of the guide](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/615bde109269124af0f01e8917c320a9f5193dcc/GUIDE.md#creating-a-component). It works something like an event handler, where a query is raised on the component whenever the element comes into existence or is removed. If you use a query that updates a reference in the component state you can be sure to know that you always have the actual element you want (or `Nothing` if it doesn't exist for some reason).

If you *really* want to use `getElementById` then [it is available from `purescript-dom`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-dom/3.3.1/docs/DOM.Node.NonElementParentNode#v:getElementById). It's not part of Halogen, as Halogen is not for general purpose DOM manipulation. Those utility functions are only provided to make it easier to initialise a Halogen app.